# an online WYSIWYG editor, drag and drop editor

Tags: drag-and-drop, e-commerce, wysiwyg, shopping-cart, sms-gateway

Hello Stack community I m deepak a fellow user of your site.

My question to you was regarding and online WYSIWYG editor, as i wanted to develop a website for a client which is an e-commerce site(dynamic) so I started working on "opencart" and many other tools like "nopcommerce" which haves cart,email notification,sms api and indian currency option available to that particular tool if not then can be integrated later on.
Now the client is in need of a  show-off e-commerce site which have the advance views like parallax scrolling if not then extra views to be added which is most likely to be seen in an static show-off site with basic features of email and sms api to be included in the website

I started using template and dreamweaver to work on but I was unable to do so as I don't know about any standalone cart software which can be integrated to a live website or template so i moved on to Drag n Drop website editor which haves indian currency like "wix" but due to some reasons i was limited by the features of "wix"

I wanted to know what are the other option would I have now as the most of the time has passed out and the client want the site to be live in faster basis,
so I am requesting an answer of what to do now is there any other editor like "wix" which have all the three functions (sms api, email notifications,indian currency) available or any other way of using tools, template, software or something like "open cart" or dreamweaver/template if any or else do i have an option to edit the whole view of open cart as I want to edit all the basic structure of open cart and change the colour theme of open cart from blue to orange, if yes then how ?

I hope that i would get the answer or help what i m looking for in  community

Regards,
Deepak Verma